# heavy customized routing constraint slowing site down?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing

It doesn't happen all the time, but after some heavy use it seems my site slows down a lot, the only code I have changed has been changing the redirects.

The routing finds old categories (that aren't in use anymore) and replaces them with their new category. so someone how goes to example.com/scary-shows/buffy will be redirected to example.com/television/buffy

I am trying to figure out the performance loss (if it's even happening here), and where I can improve it.

Global.asax:

```
...
// custom constraint
    routes.MapRoute("ArticlesCategories", "{category}/{page}",
       new { controller = "Custom", action = "CategoryRedirect" },
       new { isCategory = new CategoryRouteConstraint() });

    //Article routes            
    routes.MapRoute("ArticlesRedirect", "Articles/Redirect",
       new { controller = "_Articles", action = "Redirect" });
             routes.MapRoute("ArticlesSubcategories", "articles/categories/{filter}/{section}",
                    new { controller = "_Articles", action = "Filter", filterBy = "categories", section = UrlParameter.Optional });
          routes.MapRoute("ArticlesTags", "articles/tags/{filter}",
    new { controller = "_Articles", action = "Filter", filterBy = "tags" });
...
```

Constraint:

```
   public class CategoryRouteConstraint:IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
                          RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            string page = string.Format("{0}", values["page"]);
            string urlCategory = string.Format("{0}", values["category"]);

            if (GetCategoryDictionary().ContainsKey(urlCategory))
            {
                string topCategory = GetCategoryDictionary()[urlCategory];
                values.Add("topCategory",topCategory);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


        private static List<Category> _categoryList = null;
        private static object _lockObj = new object();
        private static Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = null;

        private static Dictionary<string, string> GetCategoryDictionary()
        {
            if (_dictionary != null) return _dictionary;

            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                //check again...
                if (_dictionary != null) return _dictionary;
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"my-old-example-category", "example"},
                        {"blogs", "Blog"},
                        {"doctor-notes", "Blog"},
                        {"action-movies", "movies"},
                        {"reality-tv", "television"},
                        {"scary-shows", "televsion"},
                        ... this goes on for about 100 more categories ...
                    };

                _dictionary = dictionary;
                return dictionary;
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10800)]
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CategoryRedirect()
    {
        string topCategory = string.Format("{0}", RouteData.Values["topCategory"]);
        string page = string.Format("{0}",RouteData.Values["page"]);

        return RedirectPermanent(string.Format("/{0}/{1}", topCategory, page));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can reproduce this performance issue you should just try to use VS Profiler to get information where you have problem. And btw, instead of verifying and getting key use just one operation [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing

Answer (score 0):

You could optimise your code a bit:

- Use .ToString() instead of string.Format (string.format uses expensive regex)
- Use TryGetValue() instead of your 2 operations
- Init the dictionary on app start or even consider dropping the dictionary at all, an large switch statement with a returned string is faster than the dictionary